# Returning object depending on a value in a generic way

Tags: java, inheritance, switch-statement, generic-programming

Consider I have many classes, that **all inherit from the same class** :

```
public class A
{
  ...
}

public class AA extends A
{
  ...
}

public class AB extends A
{
  ...
}

public class AC extends A
{
  ...
}
```

And then in some other part of the code, I would like to return one of the child class, depending on a value sent to that function, as follow :

```
public A getChild(int value, Object foo)
{
    switch(value)
    {
        case 0: {
            return new AA(foo);
        }
        case 1: {
            return new AB(foo);
        }
        case 2: {
            return new AC(foo);
        }
        default: {
          return new AA(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, I only have 3 types of children. But I could have let's say 30 of these, and the `switch` statement would become huge.

Is there any way to do the same thing using something else that a `switch` statement and that would be more generic? Like function pointers in C?

Comment: Well you wont come around a part with an `if-else` like behaviour as you have to decide on which `value` which type of instance is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mapping of integer values to functional interfaces that create instances of the various sub-classes of `A`:

```
Map<Integer,Function<Object,A>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(0,f -> new AA(f));
map.put(1,f -> new AB(f));
...
```

Then use the mapping as follows:

```
public A getChild(int value, Object foo) {
    return map.getOrDefault(value, f -> new AA(f)).apply(foo);
}
```

Comment: Seems good! I need to change some stuff in my code, then I will implement it and let you know. Thanks :)

Comment: would recommend to use `Function<? super Object, ? extends A>` instead of `Function<Object,A>` for some rare cases

Comment: @Eran I have a question thought. What if child classes take several parameters?

Comment: @souki this solution currently supports only a single parameter. If you want multiple parameters, you could use a `Map<Integer,Function<Object[],A>>` and let each constructor take an array of Objects, but that's getting ugly. Or, if all the child classes take multiple parameters which are the same for all of them, you can use a different functional interface instead of Function, to support as many parameters as you need.

Comment: Ok, yes you're right, it would get ugly. Hopefully they will all have the same arguments, so using a different functional interface seems to fit my needs. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In java there is a similar concept of function pointers in C.
You can use the Java Reflection (but is not so efficient):

```
public A getChild(String className, Object foo)
{
   Class c = Class.forName(className);
   return (A) c.newInstance(Object foo);
}
```

And you can use a Map to keep associations between "int value" and "String className".
But this solution is not efficient! 
Instead you can use a Map of Function as suggested by Eran.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! :)

Comment: You have some `checked` exceptions which should be taken care of

Comment: `newInstance()` takes no arguments.